# Python Index out of range on Cash flow

Tags: python, indexing

Having trouble with a code that should read comma separated values out of .txt file, sort into arrays based on negativity, and then plot data. 
Here is the code, followed by 2 .txt files, the first one works, but the second one doesn't

```
#check python is working
print "hello world"

#import ability to plot and use matrices
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

#declare variables
posdata=[]
negdata=[]
postime=[]
negtime=[]
interestrate=.025


#open file
f= open('/Users/zacharygastony/Desktop/CashFlow_2.txt','r')
data = f.readlines()

#split data into arrays
for y in data:
    w= y.split(",")
    if float(w[1])>0:
        postime.append(int(w[0]))
        posdata.append(float(w[1]))
    else:
        negtime.append(int(w[0]))
        negdata.append(float(w[1]))

print "Inflow Total: ", posdata
print "Inflow Time: ", postime
print "Outflow Total: ", negdata
print "Outflow Time: ", negtime

#plot the data
N=len(postime)
M=len(negtime)

ind = np.arange(N+M)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, posdata+negdata, width, color='r')

# add some
ax.set_ylabel('Cash Amount')
ax.set_title('Cash Flow Diagram')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')

plt.plot(xrange(0,M+N))
plt.show()'
```

.txt 1_***_*____**

```
0,3761.97
1,-1000
2,-1000
3,-1000
4,-1000
```

.txt 2_***_*__*_*_**

```
0,1000
1,-1000
2,1000
3,-1000
```

My error is as follows:

```
>>> runfile('/Users/zacharygastony/cashflow.py', wdir=r'/Users/zacharygastony')
hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zacharygastony/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/zacharygastony/cashflow.py", line 24, in <module>
    if float(w[1])>0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: As a side note, if you're having a hard time reading and parsing CSV files (or, really, even if you aren't) you should consider using either the `csv` module in the standard library and/or numpy's CSV functionality instead of trying to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

One error that I can spot is with " if float(w[1])>0:" -- it shoudl take into account that the w[1] would be a set of two values separated by a space. Here is how w would look like for the second file: "['0', '1000 1', '-1000 2', '1000 3', '-1000\n']". So, w[1] would be "1000 1" and taking a float for this value would be an error. So, if you really want to access the second element, then one way is to split it using the default space delimiter and pick the first one (or the second one). Something like: "if float((w[1].split())[0])>0:".

Comment: turns out the reason it wouldn't work is because my .txt file had extra blank lines at the bottom i didn't see. Is it possible to check in my "if" statement if it's first blank, and if so, to ignore those lines?

Comment: That did cross my mind, but then with w[1] being two words, I did not go there! To ignore those lines, we can always check if the length of w is zero.. Something like: "if len(w) == 0: continue"

Comment: Come to think of it, since you are using w[1], you probably should check that w has at least two elements: "if len(w) < 2: continue"

Answer (score 0):

Without having your actual files (or, better, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the same problem), there's no way to be exactly sure what's going wrong. When I run your code (just changing the hardcoded pathname) with your exact data, everything works fine.

But, if `if float(w[1])>0:` is raising an `IndexError`, clearly `w` has only 0 or 1 elements.

Since `w` came from `w= y.split(",")`, that means that `y` didn't have any commas in it.

Since `y` is each line from your file, one of the lines doesn't have any commas in it.

Which line? Well, none of them in the example you gave.

Most likely, your *real* file has something like a blank line at the end, so `w` ends as the single-element list `['']`.

Or… maybe that `2______` is actually a header line at the top of your file, in which case `w` will end up as `['2______']`.

Or the actual file you're running against is a longer, hand-edited file, where you've made a typo somewhere, like `4.1000` instead of `4,1000`.

Or…

To actually figure out the problem instead of just guessing, you will need to debug things, using a debugger or an interactive visualizer, or just adding `print` statements to log all the intermediate values:

```
print(y)
w= y.split(",")
print(w)
w1 = w[1]
print(w1)
f = float(w1)
print(f)
if f>0:
    # ...
```

---

So, your actual problem is blank lines at the end of the file. How can you deal with that?

You can skip over blank lines, or skip over lines without enough commas, or just handle the exception and continue on.

For example, let's skip over blank lines. Note that `readlines` leaves the newline characters on the end, so they won't actually be *blank*, they'll be `'\n'` or maybe, depending on your platform and Python version, something else like `'\r\n'`. But really, you probably want to skip over a line with nothing but spaces too, right? So, let's just do call `strip` on it, and if the result is empty, skip the line:

```
for y in data:
    if not y.strip():
        continue
    w = y.split(",")
```

If you'd prefer to preprocess things, you can:

```
data = f.readlines()
data = [line for line in data if line.strip()]
```

The problem with this is that, on top of reading in the whole file and searching for newlines to split on and building up a big list (all of which you were already doing just by calling `readlines`), you're *also* now going over the whole list again and building up another list. And all that before you even get started. And there is no reason to do that.

You can just iterate over a file, without ever calling `readlines` on it, which will grab the lines as you need them.

And you can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension to "preprocess" without actually doing the work up-front. So:

```
data = (line for line in f if line.strip())
```

Comment: turns out the reason it wouldn't work is because my .txt file had extra new lines at the bottom i didn't see. Is it possible to write a preliminarily goes through and deletes empty lines?

Comment: @ZacharyGastony: Of course there is. But why not just do it on the fly? Let me edit my answer to show you what I mean.